# Antivirus software blocks Electron.Net build

Tags: node.js, npm, electron, npx, electron.net

I'm trying to create a release build for my Electron.Net application via `electronize build /target win`.

But during the process, my companies antivirus software blocks the process because of an "**Unauthorized file encryption**". It seems to happen when the build result is copied/moved to `/bin/Desktop/`.

Now I can't figure out what exactly I have to whitelist so the antivirus software keeps silent during the build.

According to the antivirus, the blocked script lies in
`c:/users/{user}/roaming/npm-cache/_npx/{some-random-cache-number}/node_module/electron-builder/node-modules/app-builder-bin/win/x64/`

We've already created a whitelist for the whole folder
`c:/users/{user}/roaming/npm-cache/_npx/`

Any tips are greatly appreciated since I'm not experienced in regards to antivirus software configuration and tracking down issues like this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with electron-builder. It's being falsely detected.
https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/4901

Please update all to the newest version of Electron.NET.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. For me, it was a mixture of Updating Electron.NET as well as updating my antivirus software.